# Mysql: search for a substring and return the one with the highest # to the right of it

Tags: mysql

I need to search a string in a mysql field for a substring and return the number to the right of it, if it is the highest number of all the rows returned. (The word will most likely occur many times in the string.)

```
SELECT max(cast(substring(mq.my_query_string, (locate("near/", mq.my_query_string)+5), 2) as signed)) AS "MaxNearDistance" 
FROM my_query mq, my_test mt 
WHERE mt.company_id = 123 
      AND mq.search_query_id = mt.my_query_id 
      AND locate("near/", mq.my_query_string) > 0;
```

This works, but it only gives me the highest number of the FIRST substring and among all rows returned.  I need the highest number among ALL hits for the substring and among all rows.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Example data would help. Are there words besides 'near' and are all numbers 5 digits?

Comment: The numbers are 1 to 2 digits and will appear like this: "near/12".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table- numbers- with every number string I want to be able to find ('0' - '99' for you) then join it to my data like:

```
SELECT
  mq.my_query_string, MAX(numbers.ns)
FROM my_query AS mq
JOIN numbers ON CONCAT(mq.my_query_string, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('%near ', numbers.ns, ' %')
GROUP BY mq.my_query_string
```

I'm `CONCAT`ing a space to the data so that '11' won't match '1'.

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fda1c/4

(Actually, the right way is to normalize your data so you have a table of my_query_nears with one value per row but sometimes we must play the hand we are dealt.)